# pandas - group and count nunique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe df:

```
User,C,G
111,ar,1
112,es,1
112,es,1
112,es,2
113,es,2
113,es,3
113,es,3
114,es,4
```

What I would like to return as output is:

```
G,nU,ar,es
1,2,1,1
2,2,0,2
3,1,0,1
4,1,0,1
```

Basically, for each `G`, I'm counting the number of different `User` inside it on the `nU` column and the occurrences of the strings in `C`. Each User has a unique `C` value.
For instance, in the `G` number 1 I have two Users (111 and 112), with one occurrence in 'ar' and one in 'es' (no matter if there are two 112 occurrences, I just need the (112,'es') single couple). Summing up the 'ar' and 'es' columns should return the `nU` column. So far I tried this:

```
d = df.reset_index().groupby('G')['User'].nunique()
```

which correctly returns the count of Users but no information about the `C` column.

Sorry for the confusion this might cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `df`,

```
result = df.groupby(['G', 'User'])['C'].value_counts()
```

yields

```
G  User    
1  111   ar    1
   112   es    2
2  112   es    1
   113   es    1
3  113   es    2
4  114   es    1
dtype: int64
```

This counts each occurrence of `ar` and `es`. We really only want to count unique occurrences, so let's set each value in the Series to 1:

```
result[:] = 1
```

so that `result` looks like

```
G  User    
1  111   ar    1
   112   es    1
2  112   es    1
   113   es    1
3  113   es    1
4  114   es    1
dtype: int64
```

Now if we group by the first and last index levels (the `G` values and the `C` values), and sum each group,

```
result = result.groupby(level=['G',-1]).sum()
```

we get

```
G    
1  ar    1
   es    1
2  es    2
3  es    1
4  es    1
dtype: int64
```

Now we can unstack the last index level:

```
result = result.unstack()
```

to obtain

```
   ar  es
G        
1   1   1
2 NaN   2
3 NaN   1
4 NaN   1
```

Fill the NaNs with zeros:

```
result = result.fillna(0)
```

Define the `nU` column and the sum of the rows:

```
result['nU'] = result.sum(axis=1)
```

and reorder the columns:

```
result = result[['nU', 'ar', 'es']]
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data')
result = df.groupby(['G', 'User'])['C'].value_counts()
result[:] = 1
result = result.groupby(level=['G',-1]).sum()
result = result.unstack()
result = result.fillna(0)
result['nU'] = result.sum(axis=1)
result = result[['nU', 'ar', 'es']]
```

yields

```
   nU  ar  es
G            
1   2   1   1
2   2   0   2
3   1   0   1
4   1   0   1
```